# Hypothesis testing using the non-parametric bootstrap

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, bootstrap

## Context

I'm creating a function in R that performs a hypothesis testing using the non-parametric bootstrap. I've been following equations by my professor and though I've written some of the function, I don't understand it nor can I confirm that it does what I intend it to do.

```
#' Tests a hypothesis using the nonparametic bootstrap
#' 
#' @param x the vector containing a sample (not a dataframe)
#' @param a the quantity to test
#' @param statistic the statistic function to use e.g. mean, median. this function must take in a vector and return a single number
#' @param type the type of test. either `'left'`, `'right'`, or `'two-tailed'`
test <- function (x, a, statistic = mean, type = 'two-tailed', gens = 1000) {
  b <- statistic(x)
  # a new vector created by shifting all the values of the vector by 'removing b' and 'adding a'
  # the resulting vector should have an aggregate of `a`
  x_a <- x - b + a

  bootstrap_samples <- do(gens) * (sample(x_a, size = x_a %>% length, replace = TRUE) %>% statistic)

  # not equal
  if (type == 'two-tail') {
    p_value <- (sum(bootstrap_samples <= (a - abs(a - b))) + sum(bootstrap_samples >= (a + abs(a - b)))) / gens
  }
  # greater than
  else if (type == 'right') {
    p_value <- (sum(bootstrap_samples >= b)) / gens
  }
  # less than
  else {
    p_value <- (sum(bootstrap_samples <= b)) / gens
  }
  p_value
}
```

`a` along with the `type` is the null hypothesis.

e.g.

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 8) %>% `$`(mpg) %>% test(a = 16, statistic = mean, type = 'left')
# [1] 0.505
```

is testing whether 8 cylinder cars have mpg on average less than 16. The return of the function is the `p-value`.

## Questions

1. Is this function even doing what I intend it to? Am I calculating the `p_value` correctly for each case?
2. How does this work (if it does)? I see that I am shifting the values of `x` to create a new vector can calculating the `p_value` from that but I don't understand why that works if it does.

Thank you!